# Trailhead - Big Object Basics - Deploying Big Objects

Tags: metadata-api, trailhead, big-object

I have a problem with deploying a new Big Object to my ORG.
My problem is related to [this step](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_dev_intermediate/modules/big_objects/units/big_objects_define_custom_big_objects) in Salesforce Trailheads.
I'm trying to deploy a big object from challenge but it's not working.
In workbench I'm not getting any errors. Just a success response with value Created = FALSE.
The same happens when I try to deploy big object from the step's example.

Any ideas? Did you deploy any Big Object successfully? Can I get any working example?

@glls **You should firstly read till the end. Then you will understand about what I'm asking for...**

Comment: this is not the best place to ask for a working sample of a trailhead challenge. as per [ask]: Trailhead: Questions asking for assistance with finding resources to answer specific Trailhead Questions or for help resolving issues with Trailhead DE Orgs are welcome. Questions asking for a direct answer to a Trailhead Question are not acceptable and will be deleted.

Trailhead is intended to demonstrate your capabilities on an independent basis. As a Community SF.SE wants to demonstrate its support for the purity of that cause by not interfering with your personal learning experience.

Answer (score 3):

My friend found a solution for problems with deployment of big objects (Thanks Pawel!).

You need to create proper structure of folders/components in your ZIP file.

**Example:**

> **objects /** *Rider_History__b.object*
>
> **permissionSets /** *Rider_History__b.permissionSet*
>
> *package.xml*

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the folders and components within them is very critical. Some of the things to take care of should be,

1. The package.xml should always be at the root level of the folder.
2. The Object should go under the objects folder and the permission set should be in the permissionsets folder.
3. Once done, compress the file (zip it)
4. Use the metadata deploy option through workbench to try the deployment first. Use "Check Only" option to make sure nothing is going wrong.
5. Make sure you check the 'Single Package' option as well.
6. The final result normally would look like a tree structure and you should be able to check if the deployment passed or failed (along with the reason, if it failed)